# Refresh v-model

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I'm developing question paper application.
[image]

Once I type a question and hit the "+" button, the question goes to the question paper array and counter increased by one.
The problem is after I hit the "+" button, then also the question which I have entered previously is still in the fields of the UI. **Because of I use v-model to bind the data fields.**

What I want is a method to clear those previous question data in UI.
This is something similar to reset button function.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container" v-if="counter<=5">
      <h2>Question {{counter}}</h2><hr>

      <textarea rows="7" cols="75" v-model="question"></textarea><br><br>

      1. Answer <input type="text" v-model="answer1"> <input type="radio" name="q1answer" value="1" v-model="correctAnswer"><br><br>
      2. Answer <input type="text" v-model="answer2"> <input type="radio" name="q1answer" value="2" v-model="correctAnswer"><br><br>
      3. Answer <input type="text" v-model="answer3"> <input type="radio" name="q1answer" value="3" v-model="correctAnswer"><br><br>
      4. Answer <input type="text" v-model="answer4"> <input type="radio" name="q1answer" value="4" v-model="correctAnswer"><br>
      <hr>

      Knowledge Area <select v-model="knowledgeArea">
        <option value="Maths">Mathematics</option>
        <option value="Language">Language Skills</option>
        <option value="gk">General Knowledge</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <button type="button" class="btn" @click="pushToArray" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div v-if="counter>5">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="onSubmit">Save Question Paper</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
var questionPaper = [];
export default {

    data () {

      return {
        question:'',
        answer1:'',
        answer2:'',
        answer3:'',
        answer4:'',
        correctAnswer:'',
        knowledgeArea:'',
        counter:1,
        show:true

      }
    },
    methods: {

      onSubmit () {

      },

      pushToArray(){
        const formData = {
          question: this.question,
          correctAnswer: this.correctAnswer,
          answer1: this.answer1,
          answer2: this.answer2,
          answer3: this.answer3,
          answer4: this.answer4,
          knowledgeArea:this.knowledgeArea

        }
        this.counter++;
        questionPaper.push(formData);

      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a *template* data variable to use as a reset. For example

```js
const templateData = {
  question:'',
  answer1:'',
  answer2:'',
  answer3:'',
  answer4:'',
  correctAnswer:'',
  knowledgeArea:''
}

export default { // ...
```

use that to set your initial data

```js
data() {
  return {
    counter: 1,
    show: true,
    ...templateData
  }
}
```

Now you can easily reset your data in the `pushToArray` method, eg

```js
questionPaper.push(formData);
Object.assign(this, templateData);
```